# Find the derivative of $\int_a^{g(x)} f(t)dt $ wrt $x$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives

**Question :**

Let $$f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb R$$ be continuous  and $$g:[c,d]\rightarrow \mathbb R$$ be  differentiable .  Define  $$\psi(x) := \int_a^{g(x)} f(t)dt $$ . Prove  that $\psi$ is  differentiable and  compute  the  derivative .

**My Attempt :**

Define $$F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)dt$$
Then by *Second* *Fundamental* *Theorem*   of  Calculus , we  have $F$  is  differentiable  and  $F'=f$ at  the points  of  continuity  of  $f$ .
Then $$\psi(x)=(g\circ F)(x)$$

Both  being  differentiable ,  their  composition  is  so   and  hence  $\psi$  is  differentiable. And  by  *Chain* *Rule*  we  have , $$\psi'(x)=g'(F(x))F'(x) \\ =(g'(F(x)))\cdot f(x)$$
Upto  this  is  I  think  ok. But  now  how to  simplify $g'(F(x))$ $?$

Comment: In your last line of the question what is $h$ ?

Comment: @S.Panja-1729 : Typo Sir,typo.

Answer (score 3):

Your function is  $\psi(x)=F(g(x))-F(a)$ Where $F(x)$ is a primitive of $f(x)$ so the derivative is:
$$
\psi'(x)=F'(g(x))g'(x)=f(g(x))g'(x)
$$

Answer (score 3):

You have a mistake. The composition is

$$\psi (x) = \left( {F \circ g} \right)(x)$$

and hence you have

$$\eqalign{
  & \psi '(x) = F'(g(x))g'(x)  \cr 
  & \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, = g'(x)f(g(x)) \cr} $$

Answer (score -1):

You did the composition wrong! The integral is $F\circ g(x)$ and not $g\circ F(x)$.